# Dictionary assignment "invalid literal for int()" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to assign a new value to a key in a dictionary. But getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"
Here is what I do.

```
balance = {'beer':5, 'toast':2}
item = input("what did you eat?: ")
price = input("how much?: ")
if item not in balance:
   balance[item] = int(price)
else:
   balance[item] = balance[item] + int(price)
```

I'm puzzled, since I can do balance['beer'] = 5 in python shell, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message again:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

This means, that you are passing an invalid argument to function `int()`, i.e. a string that does not represent a valid decimal number.

Check what `price` name holds. As it's taken from the user, your program must be prepared to handle a situation when it's garbage. I usually make a function to handle the boilerplate:

```
def input_int(prompt):
    while True:
        data = input(prompt)
        try:
            return int(data)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a valid number. Try again.")
```

You can also add some escape condition if it makes sense in your program.

Comment: Thank you, need to try that.

Answer (score 2):

what is the value of `price`

it is probably a string?

having a value that cannot be converted to an [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#int) will cause this

```
>>> test = 'test'
>>> int(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'
```

also please make sure to post your complete traceback as python gives it to you in your question, not just the error string

This is a great opportunity to learn about data validation, as you can see your program requires an integer.  You can handle this yourself, displaying your own message to the user, or allow the program to just error (assuming the client of your program will understand the error)

There are no shortcuts to data validation

```
try:
  price = int(input("how much?: "))
catch ValueError:
  print('Please enter an integer')
```

or something to that effect